# How can I ensure that my ASP.NET application is sharing only one instance of a DLL?

Tags: asp.net, dll, workflow, client, client-server

I have a DLL that runs the back-end and DB connections for a website that involves interactivity between individual sessions from seperate clients - i.e. chat etc.

The problem is, if 1000 people are browsing this website, I want all the various instances of my ASP.NET application sharing a single instance of this DLL - so I can manage all of the incoming and outgoing information in a single place.

How can I specify that only one instance of my back-end DLL should be used for the entire website, regardless of the number of clients who are connected?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your assembly is added to the GAC you're only using one DLL. And if
you only want one instance running than it's called a "singleton" design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try using multithreaded singleton pattern

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx